# Changing cookie value doesn't work (php 5.6)

Tags: php, cookies

When the user logs in to the website, it saves a cookie with the jwt token.

However, when logging out, I'm trying to put this token with null heat but it doesn't work. I've searched everywhere on the web and tried all the ways I found but it just doesn't work.

Can someone help me ?

```
public function emailLogin($email, $password) {
        $response = (new GraphQLController())->emailLoginWeb($email, $password);
        $response = json_decode($response);

        if ($response->data->emailLoginWeb) {
            $user = new \stdClass();
            $user->name = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->name;
            $user->birthday = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->birthday;
            $user->children = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->children;
            $user->gender = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->gender;
            $user->maritalStatus = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->maritalStatus;
            $user->phone = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->phone;
            $user->state = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->state;
            $user->email = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->email;
            $user->token = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->token;
            $user->cities = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->cities;
            $user->hasPassword = true;
            $user->user_id = $response->data->emailLoginWeb->_id;
            $this->session = Session::getInstance('SESSID');
            $this->session->offsetSet('user', $user);
        }

        setcookie('ms_gateway_token', $response->data->emailLoginWeb->token, time() + 3652500);
        return json_encode($response);
    }


public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        setcookie(session_name(), "", time() - 3600);
        setcookie("iumc", "", time() - 3600);
        $this->session = Session::getInstance('SESSID');
        $this->session->offsetUnset('user');
        $this->session->destroy();

   setcookie('deslogou', " ");
    setcookie('ms_gateway_token', " ", time() - 3600);

        $this->redirect('/login');
    }
```

Note: the login part works, it saves the cookie normally, it doesn't work when changing the cookie value.

Comment: No one should log into any site that still runs on PHP 5.6 in 2023 in the first place. Stop endangering your site user's data and privacy, and bring this up to a current PHP version first of all.